# Filter strings in a for loop by list of words for reddit bot

Tags: python, for-loop, praw

So I'm trying to write a reddit bot to find articles with certain words in the title.  Here's what I have so far:

```
top_posts = page.hot(limit=20)
for post in top_posts:
    title = post.title
    if title.lower() in ['word1',  'word2', 'word3']:
        print(title)
```

If I replace the last 2 lines with...

```
    if 'word1' in title.lower():
        print(title)
```

then it'll print the titles that have `word1` in them but when I put it into a list it won't.  I want to use a list to match different spellings of the same word.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `title.lower()` isn't in `['word1',  'word2', 'word3']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the order of the operands wrongly placed and you're not doing it right.

Use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to check if *any* of words in the list is contained in the title:

```
if any(wd in title.lower() for wd in ['word1',  'word2', 'word3']):
    print(title)
```

To check if *all* of the words are contained in `title`, use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
title.lower() in ['word1',  'word2', 'word3']
```

This checks exactly what it says: Whether `title.lower()`, the lowercase `title`, is in the list of words.

This will work in cases where `title` is a single word, for example:

```
>>> title = 'Word1'
>>> title.lower() in ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
True
```

But of course, this will not work when `title` is an actual sentence that contains multiple words. `title = 'Word1 foo bar'` will never be an element of that single-word list.

So, you do have to have to check for every word from your word list whether it is contained in the `title` string:

```
>>> title = 'Word1 foo bar'
>>> 'word1' in title.lower()
True
>>> 'word2' in title.lower()
False
>>> 'word3' in title.lower()
False
```

You could do that in a loop and break out of it as soon as you hit a positive result:

```
>>> def titleContainsWords(title, words):
        for word in words:
            if word in title:
                return True
        return False

>>> wordlist = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']
>>> titleContainsWords(title.lower(), wordlist)
True
```

This is such a common thing, that there is also a shorter way to do the same thing, combining the [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function with generator expressions:

```
>>> any(word in title.lower() for word in wordlist)
True
```