# Finding preferable strings from a list

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Is it possible in python to find a specific string from a list no matter what their cases are without the help of `Regular expression`? I meant, it will look for all cases with a certain search.

Please, take a look at this below script to see what I meant:

```
container = ['meet me','Meet Me','Say Hi','say hi','MEET ME','SAY HI']
for item in container:
    if 'meet' in item:
        print(item)
```

Result I'm having:

```
meet me
```

Result I would like to have:

```
meet me
Meet Me
MEET ME
```

Comment: Just do `.lower()` on your strings.

Comment: `if 'meet' in item.lower():`

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46285510/filter-strings-in-a-for-loop-by-list-of-words-for-reddit-bot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Akavall mentioned in the comments. Simply do:

```
container = ['meet me','Meet Me','Say Hi','say hi','MEET ME','SAY HI']
for item in container:
    if 'meet' in item.lower():
        print(item)
```

This turns every string into lowercase. Therefore every type of meet (MEET, MeeT, MeEt) etc. will be turned into "meet" which will satisfy the condition of your `if` statement

conversely you *could* do `if 'MEET' in item.upper()` if you so desired. Here is the documentation on [`str.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower)

Comment: Thanks MattR, for your answer. It works as i expected. Unfortunately, I can't accept it as an answer before ten minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Adding my two cents, with a comprehension.

```
filtered = [s for s in container if 'meet' in s.lower()]
```

Comment: Need be more from this kind of answers

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
container = ['meet me','Meet Me','Say Hi','say hi','MEET ME','SAY HI']
for item in map(lambda s: s.lower(), container):
    if 'meet' in item:
        print(item)
```

Comment: Please don't start a `map` call immediately with a `lambda`. If you don't already have the function to use, use a generator comprehension.

Comment: You can do `map(str.lower, container)` instead

Comment: Note that this will print the lower case version of the item, not the original item

Answer (score 0):

do item.lower(). This will ignore the case when comparing.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `item.lower()` to ignore case and then, make the desired matches:

```
container = ['meet me','Meet Me','Say Hi','say hi','MEET ME','SAY HI']
for item in container:
    if 'meet' in item.lower():
        print(item)
```